# How and where to instantiate a custom class that extends the WP_REST_Controller

Tags: api, rest, controller, wordpress

I have a plugin that I created and I want to use the WP rest api [controller pattern](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/) in order to extend the api.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: myplugin
* Plugin URI: h...
* Description: A simple plugin ...
* Version: 0.1
* Author: Kamran ...
* Author ....
* License: GPL2

function myplugin_register_endpoints(){

   require_once 'server/controllers/my_ctrl.php';
   $items=new items();
   $items->register_routes();

}

add_action('rest_api_init','myplugin_register_endpoints');
.
.
```

I created a class a folder called server/controllers and inside it my_ctrl.php file with a class that extends WP_REST_Controller that looks like this

// server/controllers/my_ctrl.php

```
class items extends WP_REST_Controller {

    /**
    * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
    */
     public function register_routes() {
       .....
     }

}
```

However I am receiving the following error in sublime xdebuge call stack:

[Fatal error] Class 'myplugin\WP_REST_Controller' not found

I am not sure how to solve this issue, where to put the files for my custom controller, where to create the instance of the custom class etc?

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: I see the error on sublime xdebug callstack: " [Fatal error] Class 'WP_REST_Controller' not found."  after the line require_once 'server/controllers/my_ctrl.php'; PHP looks at the class and cant parse "class items extends WP_REST_Controller " I assume because it cant find WP_REST_Controller that the my items class tries to extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manged to solve the issue,
I checked the wp-content\plugins folder and I couldn't find the \rest-api folder and although I found the folder inside \wp-includes\rest-api it seems that this folder that integrates the "wp rest api" into core doesn't include all the classes that the api can expose (it includes only 3 php files), So it didn't include \wp-content\plugins\rest-api\lib\endpoints\class-wp-rest-controller.php . I installed the "wp rest api" plugin and it was added to wp-content\plugins and now I don't have the error anymore. (It was strange because I don't know when it was deleted from my project)

Thank you Dan your comments really helped me to recheck everything and scan the folders included in my wordpress and realize that the plugin  is missing and that the  folder \wp-includes\rest-api doesnt contain all the needed classes.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this and thought I'd provide my solution in case someone else encounters this.

The idea is to postpone the instantiation of the class extending `WP_REST_Controller` by not instantiating it until the actual `rest_api_init` hook is called.

Code example:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/VideoImageApi.php');
    VideoImageApi::instance()->register_routes();
});
```

Note the `require_once` from within the callback.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution for me too.